# How do you create a gesture recognizer for a custom cells button in a tableViewController that will be able to identify the cell it is in?

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, uigesturerecognizer

I have a custom cell which has a button that i am needing to recognize whether the user taps or does a long press. I am able to recognize both but the long press gesture only works for the most recent cell made, while the cells prior do nothing when the button gets long pressed.

//here is what i have in my cellForRowAtIndexPath

```
self.longPress = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleLongPressGestures:)];
longPress.minimumPressDuration = 1.0f;
longPress.allowableMovement = 300.0f;

[cell.button addGestureRecognizer:longPress];
```

//testing LP

- (void)handleLongPressGestures:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer*)sender

{
    if([sender isEqual:self.longPress]){

```
    if(sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan){
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"changeValues" sender:self];
    }
}
```

}

since it only works for the most recent cell made, i have also tried moving the initialization of the longPress properties to the view did load and assigning it to the button on creation of the cell but i still had the same results. If anyone has any insight on doing something like this it would really be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This method worked for me and although it does not use gesture recognizer, it does do what i was wanting it to so i though it would post it incase someone else came across the same issue

```
- (IBAction)numberAvailablePressed:(id)sender {

    pressedDown = NO;

}

- (IBAction)numberAvailableTouchedDown:(id)sender {
    pressedDown = YES;


    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:3.0
                                     target:self
                                   selector:@selector(checkIfPressed)
                                   userInfo:nil
                                    repeats:NO];

}

-(void)checkIfPressed
{
    if(pressedDown == YES)
    {
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"changeValues" sender:self];
    }
}
```